# Difference Between rendering The jsxVarible and jsxComponet in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

The following is my jsxVarable Having jsx Code

```
let JsxVarible = (
    <div>
    <h1>Hello this is from Jsx</h1>
    </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(JsxVarible, document.getElementById("app"));
```

EveryThing is working Fine

```
let JsxComponent = () =>(
    <div>
    <h1>We are rendering the JsxComponent</h1>
    </div>
)



ReactDOM.render(<JsxComponent />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Same thing i have done using  Jsx Component rendering

1)Why should i use jsxcomponent  when i can reneder the jsx varble data

2)I see that if i use jsxvarable ,i am unable to pass the props, except these is there any advantage?

3)I have tried the in Bable  for creating a variable  and functional Component

```
var a = /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello"));

var b = function b() {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", null, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("h1", null, "world"));
};
```

4) How function inside `ReactDom.render()` method  is called ( rendering as a component means calling a function ? what is it with class based Componentent )

Comment: You seem to have *illustrated* the difference. A component is a class that implements a `render` method that returns an element, or a function that returns an element. JSX (by default) is converted to `React.createElement`, so it's an element.

Comment: But i have a functional component not a call component

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean or why you think that's a problem. What's a *"call component"*?

Comment: I edited  can you help me

Comment: You're asking 4-ish questions, not all of which make sense. `jsxVarable` (sic) is an *element*, JSX is converted to `React.createElement` (see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx). `JsxComponent` is a (function-based) *component*. `ReactDOM.render` takes an *element*. The `Route`'s `component` prop is, no surprises, a *component*. Please read [ask], then [edit] this down to one clear question if you still have one.

Answer (score 0):

1. ReactDOM.render() method expects a render-able element in the first parameter, so you can feed that element by class component, functional component, variable or you can write jsx in there.
2. The Router component expects a class or functional component as the component prop.